# RMIIO and NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, rmi, ejb-3.1, wildfly-8, rmiio

I'm trying to upload a file from the client (JSE) to the server application (Java EE, EJB, Wildfly). I'm trying use first example from [this page](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/apidocs/overview-summary.html#overview_description), but when I try to run the server applications on the Wildfly server - I get this error:

> 19:08:30,077 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ProjectEngineerServer.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ProjectEngineerServer.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "ProjectEngineerServer.jar"
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.system.main.HandlingBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ProjectEngineerServer.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>       ... 5 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/healthmarketscience/rmiio/RemoteInputStream
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>       ... 10 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.healthmarketscience.rmiio.RemoteInputStream from [Module "deployment.ProjectEngineerServer.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       ... 15 more
>   19:08:31,657 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ProjectEngineerServer.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"ProjectEngineerServer.jar\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"ProjectEngineerServer.jar\"
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.system.main.HandlingBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ProjectEngineerServer.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/healthmarketscience/rmiio/RemoteInputStream
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.healthmarketscience.rmiio.RemoteInputStream from [Module \"deployment.ProjectEngineerServer.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}

I don't understand why the class cannot be found (`com/healthmarketscience/rmiio/RemoteInputStream`). I use a Maven and I added this to my *pom.xml*:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.rmiio</groupId>
    <artifactId>rmiio</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

So I've got the rmiio library in my project.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Step by step what i did:

1. I created the following path under the Wildfly_HOME: `WILDFLY_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\com\healthmarketscience\main` for rmiio library.
2. I added a `rmiio-2.0.5.jar` file and a `module.xml` file in the `main` directory. Here's the `module.xml` file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.healthmarketscience">
     <resources>
       <resource-root path="rmiio-2.0.5.jar"/>
     </resources>
     <dependencies>
       <module name="javax.api"/>
       <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
     </dependencies>
   </module>
   ```
3. I added a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file into the `META-INF` directory in my project. Here's the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <jboss-deployment-structure>
       <deployment>
           <dependencies>
               <module name="com.healthmarketscience" slot="main" export="true"/>
           </dependencies>        
       </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```